# Rails - how to make an instance of Google Maps accessible in views?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript

I have a file `my_app.js.coffee` and there's this setup of Google Maps:

```
map = undefined
initialize = (map) ->
    myOptions =
      center: new google.maps.LatLng 39.729001, -94.902342
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    map = new google.maps.Map $('.map')[0], myOptions

  $ ->
    initialize(map)

  return
```

And then if I use in a view `DIV` with `class="map"`, the map is displayed. That's cool.

But sometimes is needed to set up a difference center of the map.
In the respective view, I tried this:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  map.setCenter(43.652976, -79.390409);
</script>
```

But it doesn't affect the center of the map. Even though, in the console is following error message:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: map is not defined
```

What do I miss here?

Thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

```
buildMap = (callback = ->)->
    console.log('xxx')
    myOptions =
      center: new google.maps.LatLng 39.729001, -94.902342
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    console.log('b1')
    Gmaps.map = new google.maps.Map $('.map')[0], myOptions
    console.log('b2')
    #addMarkers(Gmaps.map)
    callback()

console.log('ccc')
Gmaps =
  buildMap: buildMap

window.Gmaps = Gmaps
```

Answer (score 1):

`map` is a local variable inside your file.

An ugly fix would be to replace it with `window.map`

You should think about the scope of your variables and your dependencies. Its a huge topic.

In the first place I'd do as follows:

```
Gmaps = 
  buildMap: (callback = ->)->
    myOptions =
      center: new google.maps.LatLng 39.729001, -94.902342
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    Gmaps.map = new google.maps.Map $('.map')[0], myOptions
    callback()

window.Gmaps = Gmaps
```

then to create the map in your views:

```
Gmaps.buildMap()
```

to create and change center:

```
Gmaps.buildMap(function(){
  Gmaps.map.setCenter(43.652976, -79.390409);
})
```

Comment: Unfortunately still no map. Won't be there something wrong with the line `Gmaps.map = new google.maps.Map $('.map')[0], myOptions` as the `console.log` statement after this line that print out anything?

Comment: what if you do `$(function(){ Gmaps.buildMap() 
 })`

Comment: The great news is that is working! Thanks! But when I try to set the new center, like: `$(function(){ Gmaps.buildMap(function(){
  Gmaps.map.setCenter(43.652976, -79.390409);
  Gmaps.map.setZoom(5);
}) })` - nothing happens right now, and no JS error in the console.

Comment: try `Gmap.map.setCenter({lat: 43.652976, lng: -79.390409});` btw, consider using gmaps4rails...

Comment: It unfortunately didn't help, also tried `Gmap.map.setCenter(new GLatLng(43.652976, -79.390409), 10);`, but without success too. Will take a look for that gem.

Comment: what is `GLatLng`? check doc https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map (and an upvote would be fair)

Comment: That's weird, doesn't work `setCenter` nor `setZoom`... it looks like it can't access the Google Maps attributes from the function (I upvoted and marked it, thanks - forgot to do it sooner).

Comment: A note - when I use this code: `Gmapsx.mmmap.setZoom(12);` - it doesn't return any error message or warning of using incorrect functions/variables

Comment: just made a plunkr to try to understand, but it just works: http://plnkr.co/edit/Jjm5JTBwHhBTtZNsupiV?p=preview

Comment: Hmm... I don't get it. If I try to "activate" the map, it's working, but if I try to set zoom or change the center, it doesn't... Double checked the JS Coffee file and it's the same as on plunkr or here on SO.

Comment: Sorry, I cant do much more than providing a working prototype